# Cannot set watermark thru YouTube API using Google PHP Client Library

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I am using the new Google API PHP Client Library from GitHub. Here is the code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId( 'CLIENTID' );
$client->setClientSecret( 'CLIENTSECRET' );
$client->refreshToken( 'REFRESHTOKEN' );
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube( $client );
$channelId = 'UC...';
$imagePath = "./image.jpeg";
$postBody = new Google_Service_YouTube_InvideoBranding();
$postBody->setImageBytes( filesize( $imagePath ) );
$postBody->setTargetChannelId( $channelId );
$imageData = file_get_contents( $imagePath );
$resource = array(
    'data' => $imageData,
    'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg,image/png,application/octet-stream',
    'uploadType' => 'media'
);
$youtube->watermarks->set( $channelId, $postBody, $resource );
```

But I got the following exception:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/upload/youtube/v3/watermarks/set?channelId=UC...&uploadType=multipart): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ....../src/Google/IO/Stream.php on line 109
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect' in ....../src/Google/IO/Stream.php:112
Stack trace:
#0 ....../src/Google/Http/REST.php(46): Google_IO_Stream->makeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#1 ....../src/Google/Client.php(492): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#2 ....../src/Google/Service/Resource.php(194): Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#3 ....../src/Google/Service/YouTube.php(2687): Google_Service_Resource->call('set', Array)
#4 .../watermark.php(48): Google_Service_YouTube_Watermarks_Resource->set('UC...', Object(Google_Service_YouTube_InvideoBranding), Array)
#5 {main}
  thrown in ....../src/Google/IO/Stream.php on line 112
```

Similar to "set thumbnail". Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Google_Http_MediaFileUpload to upload the image file.

Here's an example: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/upload_thumbnail.php#L78

Comment: I followed the example but still get 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect' Exception.

Comment: Is this a bug? It's calling `file_get_contents(/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set...)` instead of `file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/upload/...)`

Comment: I added `https://www.googleapis.com` in the client library and it seems running but I got 'forbidden' exception. I have no problem edit video meta data using client library and the same authentication.

Comment: It seems the latest commit fix this bug. But I got 

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set?videoId=...&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEn...: (403) Forbidden' in ....../src/Google/Http/REST.php:74
Stack trace:
#0 ....../src/Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php(162): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#1 ....../....php(66): Google_Http_MediaFileUpload->nextChunk('??????JFIF?????...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in ....../src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 74
`

Comment: You may not have the rights for your account to set watermarks for that specified channel. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/watermarks/set#youtube.watermarks.set-forbidden-forbidden

Comment: I can update video. If I have `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`, do I need `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload`?

Comment: It turns out it's the problem of my account.

Comment: @xuc - I'm getting the same error now (403, forbidden).  What ended up being the problem on your account?

Comment: you can check http://www.youtube.com/features to see if your account is eligible for custom thumbnails. your account needs to be verified and in good standing to do so.

Comment: @Rob my testing account is actually company account, and does not have full access like my personal account.

Comment: @IbrahimUlukaya Thanks - that was the issue.  Didn't realize that the account I was trying to upload a thumbnail to had to be verified.  Seems weird to make that distinction at the user account level, but whatever.  At least I know now.